# print out array without stringify to Slack

Tags: node.js, slack

i'm trying to return an array that i'm creating. 
the problem is that I don't want to use stringify since it returns brackets. 
Been trying different methods but non really work, and Im not sure if its Slacks problem, or if its in my code =/

This is what I have.

```
let elements = [];
          for (let i in response.options) {
            let opt = response.options[i];
            elements.push(
              { 
                "actions"   : [
                  {
                      "name": opt.label,
                      "text": opt.label,
                      "type": "button",
                      "value": opt.value.input.text
                  }]
              }
            );
          }             
          payload = {
            "text": "Would you like to book?",
            attachments: [
              {
                "text": "Choose",
                "fallback": "You are unable to choose a game",
                "callback_id": "wopr_game",
                "color": "#3AA3E3",
                "attachment_type": "default",
                "actions": elements
              }
            ] 
          };
          console.log(payload)
```

my console returns this.

```
{ text: 'Would you like to book?',
  attachments:
   [ { text: 'Choose',
       fallback: 'You are unable to choose a game',
       callback_id: 'wopr_game',
       color: '#3AA3E3',
       attachment_type: 'default',
       actions: [Array] } ] }
```

and whit stringify

```
{ text: 'Would you like to book?',
  attachments:
   [ { text: 'Choose',
       fallback: 'You are unable to choose a game',
       callback_id: 'wopr_game',
       color: '#3AA3E3',
       attachment_type: 'default',
       actions: '{"actions":{"name":"Book transport","text":"Book transport","type":"button","value":"transport"}},{"actions":{"name":"Book hotel","text":"Book hotel","type":"button","value":"hotel"}},{"actions":{"name":"Travel Policy","text":"Travel Policy","type":"button","value":"Travel Policy"}}' } ] }
```

Any ideas on how i can return just the text so slack renders the buttons?

Thanks in advance!

Update : 
If i add a hardcoded solution to the payload, the slack buttons return correct.

```
  payload = {
            attachments: [
              {
                title: 'Do you want to interact with my buttons?',
                callback_id: '123',
                attachment_type: 'default',
                actions: [
                  {
                    "name": "yes",
                    "text": "Yes",
                    "value": "yes",
                    "type": "button",
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "no",
                    "text": "No",
                    "value": "no",
                    "type": "button",
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          };
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to set the "elements" property of the payload to just the values in the "actions.text" properties of the objects inside the array? Sounds like a job for `Array.map` :) When setting elements on the payload, try this instead:

```
"elements": elements.map(el => el.actions.text)
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this also returns  elements: [Array] } ] }

Comment: *EDIT* Nevermind, I just saw the node.js tag. What do you get in the console if you JSON.stringify() the object before printing it?

Comment: no worries. Whit stringify i get this return

elements: '{"actions":{"name":"Book transport","text":"Book transport","type":"button","value":"transport"}},{"actions":{"name":"Book hotel","text":"Book hotel","type":"button","value":"hotel"}},{"actions":{"name":"Travel Policy","text":"Travel Policy","type":"button","value":"Travel Policy"}}' } ] }

So whit stringify it returens the correct values, except its full of brackets :)

Comment: If it's stringifying to the right value, then the value is correct. It's just the console that's abbreviating it to `[Array]`, that's not the actual value in memory, so you're fine. Although if you mapped the elements to their `actions.text`, I can't imagine how you're still getting the entire element objects?

Comment: But no buttons are rendered when I use this function, If i hardcode everything it works, but as soon I want to pass the elements from the loop it breaks.

Comment: Can you post what you're using when you hardcode the elements?

Comment: I just added the code, so if i hardcode everything in the payload returns buttons correctly

Comment: Your hardcoded payload doesn't have an "elements" array. It has an "actions" array which is the individual actions from your elements. So you need to map *that*. In other words, don't use an "elements" property in your payload; use an "actions" one and set its value to `elements.map(el => el.actions)` so it's an array of actions and not an array of elements with actions.

Comment: that doesn't work either.  getting this return =/ 
actions: [Array] } ] }

Comment: Once again, the console is abbreviating your values there, but that doesn't tell you what the *actual* value is. Always use `JSON.stringify` before printing an object into the console so you can see the entire, real value. (This isn't a consideration on browsers, as most browsers will format everything for you, but Node runs in a terminal, which doesn't format it nicely.)

Comment: Found the problem. I was sending brackets with the action elements. removed them and it worked. anyhow, Thanks for your help and explanation about the console printing